# Identify correct div child to unwrap

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to unwrap a div `onClick` and show contents of another div contained within it.

The problem is that I cannot identify the correct child div to unwrap. The child div being unwrapped is always the first one that appears in HTML.

I tried to `addEventListener` inside the original `addEventListener` but that seems to overcomplicate things and results in the script being unable to tell what "style." means.

If by chance you know how I could make this code more efficient apart from solving the problem, please let me know.

```js
    function unwrapEventContainer() {
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("event_container");
        var team = document.getElementById("team_details");
        var i, y;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
            coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                if (this.style.height === "70px") {
                    this.style.height = "230px";
                    // This opens child div
                    team.style.display = "inline-block";
                } else {
                    this.style.height = "70px";
                    team.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

```css
    .event_wrapper{
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .event_container{
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        text-align: center;
        height: 70px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .team_container{
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="event_container" id="event_container" onclick="unwrapEventContainer()">
                    <p style = "display: inline-block; color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">Name of the event</p>
                    <!--JS expandable-->
                    <hr style="width: 90%">
                    <div id="team_details" style="display: none;">
                        <button class="btn_select_large">Create Team</button>
                        <button class="btn_select_large">Singleplayer</button>
                        <br>
                        <div style="padding-top: 3px;">
                            <div class="team_container">
                                <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px;">Team Name</p>
                                <button class="btn_join_small">Join ></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-top: 3px;">
                            <div class="team_container">
                                <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px;">Team Name</p>
                                <button class="btn_join_small">Join ></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="event_container" id="event_container" onclick="unwrapEventContainer()">
                    <p style = "display: inline-block; color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">Name of the event</p>
                    <!--JS expandable-->
                    <hr style="width: 90%">
                    <div id="team_details" style="display: none;">
                        <button class="btn_select_large">Create Team</button>
                        <button class="btn_select_large">Singleplayer</button>
                        <br>
                        <div style="padding-top: 3px;">
                            <div class="team_container">
                                <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px;">Team Name</p>
                                <button class="btn_join_small">Join ></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-top: 3px;">
                            <div class="team_container">
                                <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 13px;">Team Name</p>
                                <button class="btn_join_small">Join ></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wager that your problem is, that you have multiple DIVs with the "team_details" ID. Document.getElementById() always returns the first result if I recall correctly. (and HTML-IDs should be unique in any case)

Either: give unique IDs when generating your DIVs (i.e. team_details1, team_details2)
and add an "index" or "row" parameter to your function

Or: Ditch the ID altogether and use Document.getElementsByClassName(); - the list returned here will implicitly contain an index you can use to toggle the right div.

Comment: I will attempt the ClassName(); solution and let you know how it went. I wish I could give you an upvote but I don't have enough rep ._.

Comment: I might have to edit my answer, I think I would recommend going with unique IDs. `onclick="unwrapEventContainer(1/2/3/etc...)"`->`function unwrapEventContainer(row) {...
`-> `var team = document.getElementById("team_details"+row);`

Comment: Yeah, I gave the Classes a shot but no joy. The ids might not be the most efficient solution, but they will definitely be surefire. Thanks again